# No me funciona el checked que muestra la información

Tags: html, css

Quiero hacer un check que al momento de presionar la X se cierre en una pagina responsive
Al hacer click en la X no pasa absolutamente nada ya verifique y todos los nombres estan bien entonces no se cual es el error que estoy cometiendo
Necesito que se oculte y mientras está oculto salga una barra que va a hacer que salga de nuevo la info que estaba ocultando la X
Por favor me gustaria poder saber que error estoy cometiendo estoy perdiendo la cabeza intentando arreglar esos errores
Mi codigo es el siguiente
CSS

```
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; 
}
body{
  background-color: #dddcdc ;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1,4em;
  margin: 0;
}
p{
  margin-bottom: 1.4;
}

h1{
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
.container{
  width: 85%;
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
header{
  height: 100px;
  color: #927e71;
  background: #dddcdc;
  padding: 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu button{
  padding:0 10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.mostrar-menu,
.esconder-menu{
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor:pointer;
  display: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.mostrar-menu{
  order:1;
}
.menu button:hover,
.mostrar-menu:hover,
.esconder-menu:hover{
  color:green ;
}
#check{
  display: none;
}
/* Responsive */
@media(max-width:768px){
  .mostrar-menu,
  .esconder-menu{
    display: block;
  }
  .menu{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #dddcdc ;
    left:0;
    right: -100%;
    top:0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px 0px;
    z-index: 100;
    transition:0.8s;
  }
  .menu button{
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;

  }
  .esconder-menu{
    position:absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right:40px;
  }
 #check:checked ~ .menu{
  right: 0;
 }
}
```

Ese es el css aca está la parte de html donde el for está implementado correctamente
HTML

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}">
    <title>Index  </title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="{% static 'imagenes/Foto3.png' %}">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <label for="check" class="mostrar-menu">&#8801</label>
        <nav class="menu">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Loggin</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Registrame</button>
        </div>   
            <label for="check" class="esconder-menu">&#215</label>
        </nav>
    </header>

</body>
</html>  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí bien, quieres tener un botón que te abre el menú, y una vez abierto se pueda cerrar y que el icono cambie. Esto lo puedes hacer usando solo CSS. Y evitando dos botones.

Puedes ocultar el menú con esta regla

```
/* invisible menu */    
.menu {
  display: none;
}
```

y puedes mostrar el menu

```
/* visible menu */    
#check:checked ~ .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Cambiar los iconos del botón

```
/* Icon menu */    
label[for=check]:before {
  content: "menu";
}

/* Cambiar icono cuando hacemos click */    
#check:checked+label[for=check]:before {
  content: 'x';
}
```

**Ejemplo completo:**

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #dddcdc;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1, 4em;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 1.4;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

.container {
  width: 85%;
  max-width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  color: #927e71;
  background: #dddcdc;
  padding: 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#check {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  display: none;
}


/* Icon menu */

label[for=check]:before {
  content: "menu";
}


/* label menu */

label[for=check] {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  order: 1;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.menu button:hover,
label[for=check]:hover {
  color: green;
}


/* invisible menu */

.menu {
  display: none;
}


/* visible menu */

#check:checked~.menu {
  display: block;
}


/* Cambiar icono cuando hacemos click */

#check:checked+label[for=check]:before {
  content: 'x';
}


/* Botones login / resiter */

.menu button {
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}">
  <title>Index </title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="{% static 'imagenes/Foto3.png' %}">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check"></label>
    <nav class="menu">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Loggin</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Registrame</button>
    </nav>
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Si quieres que estos efectos se aplican a partir de un tamaño de pantalla especifico, simplemente creas tu regla @media y lo añades allí.